# Html tag is not working inside model attribute label in Yii2

Tags: php, forms, activerecord, yii2

Html tag is not working inside model attribute label in Yii2

```
  public function attributeLabels() {
            return [
       'name'=>' Name <br> Age',
            ];
        }
```

Br tag is not working there, it is showing 
 tag in UI.

```
public function attributeLabels() {
        $labels = [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'model_id' => 'Form Name',
            'user_id' => 'User Name',
        ];
        $model = $this->getFields(UcFormFields::STATIC_FIELDS);

        foreach ($model as $field)
            $labels[$field->varname] = Yii::t('app', $field->title);

        $model = $this->getFields(UcFormFields::DYNAMIC_FIELDS);

        foreach ($model as $field)
            $labels[$field->varname] = "Question \n Instruction.."; // will be replaced by variable

        $model = $this->getDepFields(UcFormFields::DYNAMIC_FIELDS);
        foreach ($model as $field)
            $labels[$field->varname] = Yii::t('app', $field->title);

        return $labels;
    }
```

The above one is actual code....

Comment: Please indent your code properly, it's very difficult to comprehend.

Comment: Sure, I've edited it now.

Comment: Try using `\n` instead of <br> and encapsulate your value in double quotes instead of single

Comment: What is the reason to this? Why you label have 2 names like `Name` and `Age`? Every property of the entity suppose  to have one label. And you should not have any html attributes in the model. That has to be handled in the view file.

Comment: Tried it, \n tag didn't appear in UI, but it is not breaking the line

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Actually, I'm using the label as Quiz question name, and below the question(label), I want to show the question's instruction.

Comment: You can use `->hint()` method to add any instruction to specific input.

Comment: Oh OK, let me try it. Thank you.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco I tried it, but it is coming below the field (text box), I want it above field (text box) and below the label. Is it possible?

Comment: <br> tag is working in hint() method, but not working in labels() method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$form->field($model, 'termsofuse')
->checkbox(['label' => Yii::t('app', 'I understand and agree to the <a href="#termsofuse">Terms of Use</a>.')])
->label(false);
```

More at [Add encodeLabel in activeLabel #4039](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4039)

Comment: But it is not happening in the Validation message like below,
"I understand and agree to the <a href="#termsofuse">Terms of Use</a> cannot be blank"..  It is coming with HTML tags